# Obtaining path in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

My Directory structure is something as below:

```
app/
   server/
         api/
            user/
                controller.js

  images/
    image1.jpeg
```

The problem is when reading image1.jpeg within controller.js I have to use a string like

```
var imagePath = __dirname + '/../../../images/images1.jpeg';
fs.readFile(imagePath, ()....
```

now the above works FINE. however what I don't like is this string '/../../../'

is there a better way to access files in the images/ folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an npm module called `node-app-root-path` to help me manage my paths within the NodeJS application.

See:
https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path

To obtain the application's root path you would do `require('app-root-path')`;

**Example:**

```
global.appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var imagePath = global.appRoot.resolve('server/images');
var img1 = imagePath + '/image1.jpeg';

fs.readFile(img1, ()....
```

Not sure whether is it a good idea or not but for this case I have stored the appRoot as a global variable and this is so that it will be available anywhere within my NodeJS application stack, even to some of my other NodeJs libraries.

There are many other usages noted in their documentation, have a look and see if it helps you too.

Answer (score 1):

Short of passing the path to `app/images` to the controller, that's about as good as you can do.

You could traverse the `module.parent` references until `module.parent` isn't set, *if* you can safely make assumptions about where your main script is. For example, if your main script is `app.js` inside `app/`, you could do something like:

```
var path = require('path');
var topLevel = module;
while (topLevel.parent)
  topLevel = topLevel.parent;
topLevel = path.dirname(topLevel.filename);

var imagesBasePath = path.join(topLevel, 'images');

// ...

fs.readFile(path.join(imagesBasePath, 'images1.jpeg'), ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `path.relative`. You'd probably want to save these as constants but you could do the following to make things more readable.

Pass in the path to your current directory as the first parameter and the path to the image itself from the same parent directory (in this case app) and it will return the relative path from the current directory to the image.

```
// returns '/../../../images/images1.jpeg'
var relativePathToImage = path.relative(
  '/app/server/api/user',           
  '/app/images/images1.jpeg');

var pathToImage = __dirname + relativePathToImage;
```